# XAllocID assertion with physiotoolkit xview on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am at my wits end.  I am so near yet so far from running WAVE from physionet.org.
I have encountered the dreaded error:
 assertion "ret != inval_id" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/libX11/libX11-1.5.0-1/src/libX11-1.5.0/src/xcb_io.c", line 528, function: _XAllocID

Having installed CYGWIN successfully, I installed XVIEW followed by WFDB according to procedure specified at
http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-windows-quick-start.shtml

The xview binaries were xview-3.2p1.4-18c-cygwin.tar.bz2

This problem I believe is the same one as in  http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2010-02/msg00110.html

The resolution proposed is either

1. To recompile the xview library from xview-3.2p1.4-21.1.fc8.src.rpm with latest patches applied    OR
2. Obtain an updated cygwin binary.

Is there an updated cygwin binary in the tar.bz2 format? If there is, I should be able to use that. This would be the simplest solution for me. Please can someone tell me where to download it from.

Regrettably, the first solution will be quite beyond my capabilities. I have already looked at how to deal with the rpm, then compiling then installing, but have been going round and round in circles. If necessary, then ofcourse that will have to be done.

I am not a professional programmer and all I am doing is helping a medical research student to use wave in her research work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of WAVE, but I don't use Windows routinely.  Another WAVE user, Ben McClelland, wrote to me a few days ago to report that Cygwin 1.7 now includes working xview packages.  I verified this on Windows 7 (and also on Windows XP), and I updated the Cygwin, XView, and WFDB installation guides on PhysioNet accordingly.

If you have a non-functional xview installation already, uninstall it.

Launch Cygwin's setup tool and select xview-devel in the package list (which is sufficient to trigger installation of all of the other packages on which it depends), then finish installing or updating Cygwin.

If you have already installed WAVE, it may just work;  if not, reinstall it.  See http://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-windows-quick-start.shtml for details.

I'm currently writing a replacement for WAVE: a browser app called LightWAVE (http://physionet.org/lightwave/).  It's usable as a viewer for PhysioBank data already, and nothing needs to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution might be to download the [xview-3.2p1.4-18 source](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/xview/src/) which contains the necessary changes to build for cygwin and is available as a regular tar archive, and then apply a patch to fix the use of XAllocID in xview (for example, as described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xview/+bug/89166)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please can you look at the link you supplied, there is no xview-3.2p1.4-18c sources at that page that I can see. All I see is a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xview/+bug/89166. Sorry if I sound ignorant, but I am not a professional programmer. If I could go to the site where I could have a link to the download site for the sources, I will be grateful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Having re-read your answr, I can understand what I need to do, and that is to apply the fix described in the link. Only question now is, where can I download thexview-3.2p1.4-18c? Please can you post a link to it? Thanks, Geraldine1

Comment: The sources are linked to from the physionet page you gave, at http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/xview/src/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use "xview-3.2p1.4-18c.tar.gz" from that page. Is that the correct one to use? I run cygwin on a windows 7 operating system. Thank you again.

Comment: I've done this work and added xview packages with the results to cygwin, so you don't have to.  See the other answer instead...